# Custom URL parameters for the beats music App

Tags: beatsmusic

The beats music App on iOS seems to support the url beatsmusic:// . I am trying to find if the App supports parameters to the URL (say track ID or playlist etc.). I tried the beats developer documentation but could not find any references to their URL scheme. Does anyone know if the App supports URL parameters and what they are?

I have already tried http://handleopenurl.com and http://wiki.akosma.com/IPhone_URL_Schemes

Update:

I was able to infer some URL parameters by looking at the "Share page" that gets generated when sharing music on beats.

Example: beatsmusic://listen/sentence/54/112/264/3
         beatsmusic://listen/albums/al577721/tracks/tr580733

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do support beatsmusic:// as a protocol on mobile platforms. In general the path match the ones you'll see from the on server, like:

http://on.beatsmusic.com/users/193
http://on.beatsmusic.com/artists/ar170

is equivalent to:

beatsmusic://beatsmusic.com/users/193
beatsmusic://beatsmusic.com/artists/ar170

That same pattern works to albums, artists, playlists, users, genres, and curators.

For tracks we emulate the listen server (which shares paths with the on server):

https://listen.beatsmusic.com/albums/al6910269/tracks/tr6910289

is equivalent to

beatsmusic://beatsmusic.com/albums/al6910269/tracks/tr6910289

The sentence is a bit different, but follows the pattern

beatsmusic://beatsmusic.com/sentence/place/activity/people/genre